# How to create a blue bar on the right side of a div box

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble putting a blue box on the right side of one of my information boxes. As you can see in the 1st box, no matter what size of the screen, the blue box is always on the edge, but in the 2nd box, the blue box changes placement depending on the size of the screen. Let me know if you need any more information. I'm new to coding, so any help would be good. Thanks.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  src: url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'poppinsmedium';
  src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px;
}
.topnav {
    background-color: rgb(84,104,217);
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'futuralight';
    font-weight:900;
 }
  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 21px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 19px;
    position: relative;
    left:2%;
  }
  .topnav a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 84%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 6px;
    left: 8%;
    background-color: white;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  }
 .topnav a:hover:before {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
.topnav a.active-menu:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 84%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom:6px;
    left: 8%;
    background-color: white;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s; 
    }
  .bigcomser{
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 80px;
  }
.bodycs{
  background-color:  #EEF0FC;
  height:8000px;
}
.comser{
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  padding-top:42px;
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  font-weight:900;
}
.abtcomser{
  padding-top: 48px;
  padding-bottom: 28px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left:10%;
  width:80%;
}
.s4s{
  position: relative;
  left:10%;
  margin-top:60px;
  height:350px;
  width:80%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow:
  0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034),
  0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048),
  0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06),
  0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072),
  0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086),
  0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.s4simage{
  width:38.3%;
  position: absolute;
  right:0%;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
}
.s4stitle{
  position: relative;
  left:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
  color:rgb(84,104,217);
  font-weight:900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
}
.s4stitle::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84,104,217);
  width:12px;
  height: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  left: -4%; 
  top: 30px; /* = padding-top of parent */
}
.s4slink{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:rgb(84,104,217);
}
.titles4s{
  padding-top:2px;
  font-size:22px;
  padding-left:4%;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight:300;
}
.s4sparagraph{
  width:55%;
  position: relative;
  left:4%;
  font-size:17px;
  top:60px;  
  font-family: 'futuralight';
}
#s4slink2{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:rgb(84,104,217);
  position: relative;
  left:4%;
  top:90px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-size:18px;
}
.adaptennis{
  position: relative;
  left:10%;
  margin-top:60px;
  height:350px;
  width:80%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow:
  0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034),
  0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048),
  0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06),
  0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072),
  0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086),
  0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.adaptenimage{
  width:38.3%;
  position: absolute;
  left:0%;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-left:10px;
}
.adapten{
  position: absolute;
  right:4%;
  padding-top:30px;
  color:rgb(84,104,217);
  font-weight:900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
}
.adapten::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84,104,217);
  width:12px;
  height: 100%;
  position:absolute;
  right: -46px; 
  top: 30px; /* = padding-top of parent */
}
.titleadap{
  position: absolute;
  right:4%;
  padding-top:71px;
  font-size:22px;
  padding-left:4%;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight:300;
}
.adappar{
  width:55%;
  position: absolute;
  right:4%;
  font-size:17px;
  padding-top:150px;  
  font-family: 'futuralight';
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 830px) and  (min-width: 760px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 759px) and  (min-width: 646px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 645px) {

  .topnav {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../CSS/stylecomser.css" />
    <title>Community Service</title>
</head>
<body class='bodycs'>
    <header class="topnav" id="topnav">
        <a class="link" href="../index.html">Home</a>
        <a class="link" href="#Academics">Academics</a>
        <a class="link" href="#Projects">Projects</a>
        <a class="active-menu" href="../Pages/communityservice.html">Community Service</a>
      </header>
      <div class='bigcomser'>
        <p class='comser'>
            Community Service
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class='abtcomser'>
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisici
            ng elit. Dicta, libero! Recusandae provident est quam quisquam.
             Sequi itaque suscipit tempore corrupti officia maxime 
             nihil consequatur perspiciatis repellat placeat sed, voluptatum vitae.lor
             em Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro similique, prov
             ident libero laudantium amet odit unde dolor eaque earum qui impedit possimus natus est
              distinctio commodi quod aut numquam temporibus?
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class='s4s'>
        <img class='s4simage' src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="Missing File">
        <p class='s4stitle'>
            <a class='s4slink' href="https://www.solve4success.org" target="_blank">Solve 4 Success</a>
        </p>
        <p class='titles4s'>
            Member
        </p>
        <p class='s4sparagraph'>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetu
            r adipisicing elit. Eaque minus ab doloribus nulla quidem esse re
            pellat, asperiores ex vero minima saepe. Est officia accusamus odio et ver
            itatis placeat sapiente laudantium?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
            consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nesciunt blanditiis alias officiis ducimus tenetur, ipsa moll
            itia dicta error aliquam aliquid aperiam est repellat iure vitae
            bum exercitationem nihil, accusam
            us libero.
        </p>
        <a id = 's4slink2' href="https://www.solve4success.org" target="_blank">solve4success.org</a>
    </div>
    <div class='adaptennis'>
        <img class='adaptenimage' src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="Missing File">
        <p class='adapten'>
                Adaptive Tennis
        </p>
        <p class='titleadap'>
            Engineer
        </p>
        <p class='adappar'>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetu
            r adipisicing elit. Eaque minus ab doloribus nulla quidem esse re
            pellat, asperiores ex vero minima saepe. Est officia accusamus odio et ver
            itatis placeat sapiente laudantium?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
            consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nesciunt blanditiis alias officiis ducimus tenetur, ipsa moll
            itia dicta error aliquam aliquid aperiam est repellat iure vitae
            bum exercitationem nihil, accusam
            us libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Adipisci vitae iste, aut tenetur natu
            s tempora error voluptates, beatae obcaecati ducimus commodi et a repellat sequi ullam eligendi, expedita modi? Obcaecati!
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class='s4s'>
        <img class='s4simage' src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="Missing File">
        <p class='s4stitle'>
            <a class='s4slink' href="https://binaryheart.org" target="_blank">BH</a>
        </p>
        <p class='titles4s'>
            Member
        </p>
        <p class='s4sparagraph'>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetu
            r adipisicing elit. Eaque minus ab doloribus nulla quidem esse re
            pellat, asperiores ex vero minima saepe. Est officia accusamus odio et ver
            itatis placeat sapiente laudantium?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
            consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nesciunt blanditiis alias officiis ducimus tenetur, ipsa moll
            itia dicta error aliquam aliquid aperiam est repellat iure vitae
            bum exercitationem nihil, accusam
            us libero.
        </p>
        <a id = 's4slink2' href="https://binaryheart.org" target="_blank">binaryheart.org</a>
    </div>
    <div class='adaptennis'>
        <img class='adaptenimage' src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="Missing File">
        <p class='adapten'>
            <a class='s4slink' href="https://ntfoodtaxi.wordpress.com" target="_blank">Food Taxi</a>
        </p>
        <p class='titleadap'>
            Engineer
        </p>
        <p class='adappar'>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetu
            r adipisicing elit. Eaque minus ab doloribus nulla quidem esse re
            pellat, asperiores ex vero minima saepe. Est officia accusamus odio et ver
            itatis placeat sapiente laudantium?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
            consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nesciunt blanditiis alias officiis ducimus tenetur, ipsa moll
            itia dicta error aliquam aliquid aperiam est repellat iure vitae
            bum exercitationem nihil, accusam
            us libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Adipisci vitae iste, aut tenetur natu
            s tempora error voluptates, beatae obcaecati ducimus commodi et a repellat sequi ullam eligendi, expedita modi? Obcaecati!
        </p>
        <a id = 's4slink2' href="https://ntfoodtaxi.wordpress.com" target="_blank">ntfoodtaxi.wordpress.com</a>
    </div>
    <div class='s4s'>
        <img class='s4simage' src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="Missing File">
        <p class='s4stitle'>
            <a class='s4slink' href="https://binaryheart.org" target="_blank">Binary Heart</a>
        </p>
        <p class='titles4s'>
            Greater Chicago Food Packing
        </p>
        <p class='s4sparagraph'>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetu
            r adipisicing elit. Eaque minus ab doloribus nulla quidem esse re
            pellat, asperiores ex vero minima saepe. Est officia accusamus odio et ver
            itatis placeat sapiente laudantium?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
            consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nesciunt blanditiis alias officiis ducimus tenetur, ipsa moll
            itia dicta error aliquam aliquid aperiam est repellat iure vitae
            bum exercitationem nihil, accusam
            us libero.
        </p>
        <a id = 's4slink2' href="https://binaryheart.org" target="_blank">binaryheart.org</a>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your CSS and HTML have quite a lot of mistakes. You can use an HTML validator and CSS Lint to check for errors. You should fix these problems first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `right` to 0 in the pseudo element and apply padding to p element.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  src: url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Futura Light/futura_light_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Teko/teko-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  src: url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Playfair Display/playfairdisplay-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'poppinsmedium';
  src: url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../Fonts/Poppins/poppins-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 21px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 19px;
  position: relative;
  left: 2%;
}

.topnav a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.topnav a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.topnav a.active-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 84%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 6px;
  left: 8%;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.bigcomser {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.bodycs {
  background-color: #EEF0FC;
  height: 8000px;
}

.comser {
  font-family: 'tekoregular';
  padding-top: 42px;
  font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
  font-weight: 900;
}

.abtcomser {
  padding-top: 48px;
  padding-bottom: 28px;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
}

.s4s {
  position: relative;
  left: 10%;
  margin-top: 60px;
  height: 350px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.s4simage {
  width: 38.3%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.s4stitle {
  position: relative;
  left: 4%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
}

.s4stitle::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -4%;
  top: 30px;
  /* = padding-top of parent */
}

.s4slink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
}

.titles4s {
  padding-top: 2px;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-left: 4%;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight: 300;
}

.s4sparagraph {
  width: 55%;
  position: relative;
  left: 4%;
  font-size: 17px;
  top: 60px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
}

#s4slink2 {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  position: relative;
  left: 4%;
  top: 90px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-size: 18px;
}

.adaptennis {
  position: relative;
  left: 10%;
  margin-top: 60px;
  height: 350px;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2.8px 2.2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.034), 0 6.7px 5.3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.048), 0 12.5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 22.3px 17.9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.072), 0 41.8px 33.4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.086), 0 100px 80px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.adaptenimage {
  width: 38.3%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.adapten {
  position: absolute;
  /* Change to 0*/
  right: 0;
  padding-top: 30px;
  color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  
  /* Add padding here*/
  padding-right: 46px;
}


.adapten::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: rgb(84, 104, 217);
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  /* Change to 0*/
  right: 0;
  top: 30px;
  /* = padding-top of parent */
}

.titleadap {
  position: absolute;
  right: 4%;
  padding-top: 71px;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-left: 4%;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
  font-weight: 300;
}

.adappar {
  width: 55%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 4%;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding-top: 150px;
  font-family: 'futuralight';
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 830px) and (min-width: 760px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 759px) and (min-width: 646px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 645px) {
  .topnav {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/stylecomser.css" />
  <title>Community Service</title>
</head>

<body class='bodycs'>
  <header class="topnav" id="topnav">
    <a class="link" href="../index.html">Home</a>
    <a class="link" href="#Academics">Academics</a>
    <a class="link" href="#Projects">Projects</a>
    <a class="active-menu" href="../Pages/communityservice.html">Community Service</a>
  </header>
  <div class='bigcomser'>
    <p class='comser'>
      Community Service
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class='abtcomser'>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisici ng elit. Dicta, libero! Recusandae provident est quam quisquam. Sequi itaque suscipit tempore corrupti officia maxime nihil consequatur perspiciatis repellat placeat sed, voluptatum vitae.lor em Lorem
      ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro similique, prov ident libero laudantium amet odit unde dolor eaque earum qui impedit possimus natus est distinctio commodi quod aut numquam temporibus?
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class='s4s'>
    <img class='s4simage' src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="Missing File">
    <p class='s4stitle'>
      <a class='s4slink' href="https://www.solve4success.org" target="_blank">Solve 4 Success</a>
    </p>
    <p class='titles4s'>
      Member
    </p>
    <p class='s4sparagraph'>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetu r adipisicing elit. Eaque minus ab doloribus nulla quidem esse re pellat, asperiores ex vero minima saepe. Est officia accusamus odio et ver itatis placeat sapiente laudantium?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur,
      adipisicing elit. Nesciunt blanditiis alias officiis ducimus tenetur, ipsa moll itia dicta error aliquam aliquid aperiam est repellat iure vitae bum exercitationem nihil, accusam us libero.
    </p>
    <a id='s4slink2' href="https://www.solve4success.org" target="_blank">solve4success.org</a>
  </div>
  <div class='adaptennis'>
    <img class='adaptenimage' src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="Missing File">
    <p class='adapten'>
      Adaptive Tennis
    </p>
    <p class='titleadap'>
      Engineer
    </p>
    <p class='adappar'>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetu r adipisicing elit. Eaque minus ab doloribus nulla quidem esse re pellat, asperiores ex vero minima saepe. Est officia accusamus odio et ver itatis placeat sapiente laudantium?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur,
      adipisicing elit. Nesciunt blanditiis alias officiis ducimus tenetur, ipsa moll itia dicta error aliquam aliquid aperiam est repellat iure vitae bum exercitationem nihil, accusam us libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
      Adipisci vitae iste, aut tenetur natu s tempora error voluptates, beatae obcaecati ducimus commodi et a repellat sequi ullam eligendi, expedita modi? Obcaecati!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class='s4s'>
    <img class='s4simage' src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="Missing File">
    <p class='s4stitle'>
      <a class='s4slink' href="https://binaryheart.org" target="_blank">BH</a>
    </p>
    <p class='titles4s'>
      Member
    </p>
    <p class='s4sparagraph'>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetu r adipisicing elit. Eaque minus ab doloribus nulla quidem esse re pellat, asperiores ex vero minima saepe. Est officia accusamus odio et ver itatis placeat sapiente laudantium?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur,
      adipisicing elit. Nesciunt blanditiis alias officiis ducimus tenetur, ipsa moll itia dicta error aliquam aliquid aperiam est repellat iure vitae bum exercitationem nihil, accusam us libero.
    </p>
    <a id='s4slink2' href="https://binaryheart.org" target="_blank">binaryheart.org</a>
  </div>
  <div class='adaptennis'>
    <img class='adaptenimage' src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="Missing File">
    <p class='adapten'>
      <a class='s4slink' href="https://ntfoodtaxi.wordpress.com" target="_blank">Food Taxi</a>
    </p>
    <p class='titleadap'>
      Engineer
    </p>
    <p class='adappar'>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetu r adipisicing elit. Eaque minus ab doloribus nulla quidem esse re pellat, asperiores ex vero minima saepe. Est officia accusamus odio et ver itatis placeat sapiente laudantium?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur,
      adipisicing elit. Nesciunt blanditiis alias officiis ducimus tenetur, ipsa moll itia dicta error aliquam aliquid aperiam est repellat iure vitae bum exercitationem nihil, accusam us libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit.
      Adipisci vitae iste, aut tenetur natu s tempora error voluptates, beatae obcaecati ducimus commodi et a repellat sequi ullam eligendi, expedita modi? Obcaecati!
    </p>
    <a id='s4slink2' href="https://ntfoodtaxi.wordpress.com" target="_blank">ntfoodtaxi.wordpress.com</a>
  </div>
  <div class='s4s'>
    <img class='s4simage' src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="Missing File">
    <p class='s4stitle'>
      <a class='s4slink' href="https://binaryheart.org" target="_blank">Binary Heart</a>
    </p>
    <p class='titles4s'>
      Greater Chicago Food Packing
    </p>
    <p class='s4sparagraph'>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetu r adipisicing elit. Eaque minus ab doloribus nulla quidem esse re pellat, asperiores ex vero minima saepe. Est officia accusamus odio et ver itatis placeat sapiente laudantium?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur,
      adipisicing elit. Nesciunt blanditiis alias officiis ducimus tenetur, ipsa moll itia dicta error aliquam aliquid aperiam est repellat iure vitae bum exercitationem nihil, accusam us libero.
    </p>
    <a id='s4slink2' href="https://binaryheart.org" target="_blank">binaryheart.org</a>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```